# Python how to get the tweet data using specific word in csv file and put it in new csv file

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I have data twitter in a CSV file (that I'm mining with a Python API). I get around 1000 lines of data. Now I want to shorten the tweet data using the specific Indonesian words “macet” or “kecelakaan” (in English “traffic” or “accident”) and put the matching rows into a new separate CSV file, just like in Excel using `find all`.

The sample data twitter is example1.csv and the new file which will be created after the search of the word "macet" or "kecelakaan" is example2.csv. But there is no result.

```
import re
import csv

with open('example1.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)

if re.search(r'macet', reader):
    for row in reader:
        myData = list(row)
        print(row)

newFile = open('example2.csv', 'w')
with newFile:
    writer = csv.writer(newFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)

print("Writing complete")
```

I use spyder for environment Python 3.6.

The CSV file is already in the same folder with Spyder. Here is the screen capture image of my CSV twitter data

[myCSVtwitterData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOygE.jpg)

updated :  [Sample of csv file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14DGP7J7URmI7b1IAGW3atVctvQhakfAJ). OS using : Windows

Comment: I would expect that code to raise an error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. You are passing a `csv.reader` object to `re.search`, but it doesn't know how to search that object. You need to pass it text or byte strings.

Comment: Because I am new to python, that was the error. where I have to put the passing object between those two. Could you please help me to fix the code @PM2Ring ?

Comment: When your code gives an error you should put the full error message into your question, inside a code block so that the format is preserved. Also, you should include a few lines of sample data, as text, not as an image, so we can test the code.

Comment: ok Sir, I already add the csv sample file @PM2Ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

In your reading loop you are passing a `csv.reader` object to `re.search`, but it doesn't know how to search that object. You need to pass it text or byte strings.

The line

```
myData = list(row)
```

converts `row` into a new list and saves it to `myData`, but it's already a list, so no conversion is necessary. And that line replaces the previous contents of `myData`, but you actually want to save all the matching rows. However, there's no need to save the rows, you can just write them to the new file as you go.

Anyway, here's a repaired version of your code. From the screen shot it looks like you only want to search the text in column 2 of the input data (which corresponds to column C in your spreadsheet). I've created a regex that searches for the whole words "macet" and "kecelakaan", the "\b" matches at word boundaries so we don't get a match if "macet" or "kecelakaan" is part of a larger word.

```
import re
import csv

# Make a case-insensitive regex to match the words "macet" or "kecelakaan"
pattern = re.compile(r'\bmacet\b|\bkecelakaan\b', re.I)

with open('example1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvFile, open('example2.csv', 'w', newline='') as newFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    writer = csv.writer(newFile)

    for row in reader:
        # Skip empty rows
        if not row:
            continue
        if pattern.search(row[2]):
            print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)

print("Writing complete")
```

I've just made a couple of improvements to that code. It now uses the `newline=''` arg to open the CSV files, and it skips any empty lines in the input CSV. And the regex now ignores the case when looking for matching words.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I already tried the code. The file example2.csv is created. But the is no data inside the example2.csv. The error was : IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Ranne Please try the new version.

Comment: Yes Sir, the revision code is working like magic. Thank you very much for your help @PM2Ring

Comment: ok Sir, sorry late, b/c this is my first time posting still don't know the rules. thx for your help @PM2Ring

Answer (score 0):

Not answering about Python. But if you have a Linux OS, you can do it in one command line :

```
grep -i "macet" exemple1.csv > exemple2.csv
```

-i is for ignore case, so it will also match "Macet"

Comment: Sure, although you need a better regex so that you don't match inside words. However, the OP is using Windows, so they may not have `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

how is it~?
this code visit rows one by one
and find cells that contain a word in word_list
and write the value list on the row

```
import re
import csv

word_list = ['macet', 'kecelakaan']

with open('example1.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('example2.csv', 'w') as newFile:

    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    writer = csv.writer(newFile, lineterminator='\n')

    for row in reader:
        new_row = [content for content in row if any(map(lambda word: word in content, word_list))]
        if(new_row != []):
            print(new_row)
            writer.writerow(new_row)

print("Writing complete")
```